# What is the correct way to call "parent function" from asynchronous callback, NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Function f1() does async job and then calls callback ('child') with results. The results are checked by the callback and if they are found to be unfit, the callback should call f1() once again. This should happen till the suitable results are returned from f1().

What is the correct way to do this in NodeJS?
My current solution:

```
function f1( args, callback ) {
  // do async job
  callback(answ); // answ is returned by async job
}


var args;
// prepare args

function f2(answ) {
  if ( anws ) return true; // Urahh, all ok
  // change args and try next call
  f1(args, f2);
}

f1( args, f2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a better design

```
function f1(a, callback) {
  console.log(a);
  callback(a, f1);              // callback points to f2
}

function f2(a, callback) {
  if (a >= 10) return;
  callback(a+1, f2);            // callback points to f1
}

// initial args = 0
f1(0,f2);
```

This way, you don't have any external state (`args` in your code). `f2` still takes care of adjusting the args, but the modifications (`a+1` in my code) are passed directly to the function that gets recalled.

Also, `f1` specifies itself in the callback as the function that should be called in the event a loop needs to take place. This way, `f2` can be used for any "parent" that might call upon it as long as the parent passes a reference to itself.

Pretty cool stuff.

Output

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

> **Hint:** there's no point in returning `true` in your `f2`. The return value of an async call can't really be used anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's an ideal flow but this would work.

```
function async () {
    return async_promise;
}

function run_async (args) {
    async(args).then(success, run_async.bind(null, args));
}

function success () {
    // fin
}

run_async(args);
```

By using promises you can make a more elegant loop, but it's still not great. Maybe need some more info to help you figure out a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Your solution is working, but I generaly use promise on this case.

Why? Cause it's generally more lisible and avoid to fall on "callback hell".

It's now working natively on Node 5.0 due to ES6 spec:

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise

For your case, I think something like that should work:

```
function promiselauch(arg){
 new Promise(function( resolve,reject ) {
  // do async job
  if(answ)
   resolve(answ); // answ is returned by async job
  else
   reject(answ)
}).then(function(anws){
   // Urahh, all ok do what you want
}, function(anws){
 promiselauch(anws); //fail so relaunch
}); 
}
promiselaunch(args);
```

Didn't test, adapt it with the idea.

Answer (score -2):

i think that your solution could work. It depends however on the context in which you are working. I suggest you to use process.nextTick() to handle this type of "recursion"
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_arg

It is important to write no-blocking code in nodejs if you want to be really async.

Comment: Maybe a misscomprehension from my part, but nexttick will just call the callback at the end of the loop event, nothing insure than the async work is done... That isn't sound like a good or working solution to me...

Comment: If there is a demending call in that function call, it is better to use nextTick to avoid that 2 functions to block the code. Maybe i wasn't clear in what i wanted to say.

Comment: There isn't anything to solve. The solution proposed by rlib works and there isn't any "standard" way to deal with this. Mine was just and advice to the user because i see often nodejs that blocks the executions because of recursion. It is better to do next call on the next tick.